# ionic Angular ngModel: ngFor loop for inner arrays

Tags: angular, ionic3, javascript-objects, ngfor

I have an object looking like this:

```
const members = {
    pokiuy45 : {
        details:{
            fullname: 'Member 1',
            age: 58
        },
        contributions:{
            100: [
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 500
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 600
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 400
                },
                {
                    date: 'date3',
                    amount: 200
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            total_points: 563,
            balance: 63,
            comments: 'random text'
        }
    },

    LoghnfLM : {
        details:{
            fullname: 'Second memeber',
            age: 31
        },
        contributions:{
            100: [
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 100
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 300
                },
                {
                    date: 'date3',
                    amount: 200
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 200
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 1000
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            total_points: 587,
            balance: 420,
            comments: 'random text'
        }
    }
}
```

The tags `pokiuy45` and `LoghnfLM` represent the members IDs. Each member has a subobject to present the details (fullname and age for example, then arrays of contributions in pools of `100` and `200`. (Actually, there may be more pools, and each member may have one or more contributions in each pool).
I would like to display each contribution in a  element, with each item displaying the name, age, date and amount of each contribution.

The end goal is to have a list looking like this...

[image]

From what I know, `ngFor` are used only with arrays. So how can I make this  happen? I have no clue as where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply transform your object into an array :

```
this.membersArray = Object.entries(this.members).map(([key, value]) => {
  value.memberName = key;
  return value;
});
```

After that, you can use it with an *ngFor loop.

Script into action :

```js
const members = {
    pokiuy45 : {
        details:{
            fullname: 'Member 1',
            age: 58
        },
        contributions:{
            100: [
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 500
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 600
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 400
                },
                {
                    date: 'date3',
                    amount: 200
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            total_points: 563,
            balance: 63,
            comments: 'random text'
        }
    },

    LoghnfLM : {
        details:{
            fullname: 'Second memeber',
            age: 31
        },
        contributions:{
            100: [
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 100
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 300
                },
                {
                    date: 'date3',
                    amount: 200
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 200
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 1000
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            total_points: 587,
            balance: 420,
            comments: 'random text'
        }
    }
}

const membersArray = Object.entries(members).map(([key, value]) => {
  value.memberName = key;
  return value;
});

console.log(membersArray);
```

### EDIT

For the HTML you have provided (without style) :

```
<div *ngFor="let member of membersArray">
  <div *ngFor="let contribution of member.contributions">
    <div>{{ member.memberName }}</div>
    <div>
      <span>{{ member.details.fullName }}</span>
      <span>contribution: {{ contribution.contributionName }}</span>
      <span>{{ contribution.date }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Amount: {{ contribution.amount }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you will also have to parse & flatten your contributions for it to work :

```js
const members = {
    pokiuy45 : {
        details:{
            fullname: 'Member 1',
            age: 58
        },
        contributions:{
            100: [
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 500
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 600
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 400
                },
                {
                    date: 'date3',
                    amount: 200
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            total_points: 563,
            balance: 63,
            comments: 'random text'
        }
    },

    LoghnfLM : {
        details:{
            fullname: 'Second memeber',
            age: 31
        },
        contributions:{
            100: [
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 100
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 300
                },
                {
                    date: 'date3',
                    amount: 200
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    date: 'date1',
                    amount: 200
                },
                {
                    date: 'date2',
                    amount: 1000
                }
            ]
        },
        stats: {
            total_points: 587,
            balance: 420,
            comments: 'random text'
        }
    }
}

const membersArray = Object.entries(members).map(([key, value]) => {
  value.memberName = key;
  value.contributions = Array
    .prototype
    .concat
    .apply(
      [], 
      Object
        .entries(value.contributions)
        .map(([cKey, cValue]) => {
          cValue.forEach(v => v.contributionName = cKey);
          return cValue;
        })
    );
  return value;
});

console.log(membersArray);
```

Comment: I get that, but how will I be able to print in each `<ion-item>` the member's details and the contribution details? My challenge is, member details (name and age) are in one sub-object and contributions are in an array, from another sub-object. So is it possible, in a `ngFor` loop to read properties from a contribution and read the details of the corresponding member?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue not sure about your end goal there. Please explain through the expected object result you would like (or the expected HTML).

Comment: I edited the question, adding an HTML rendering of what it should look like at the end